# Discord content must be 2000 or fewer in length in a roles list

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i know this error is already solved but in another form i could't solve my error:

```
    if(msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}roles`)) {
        const spaces = '                      ';
        const roles = [];
        msg.guild.roles.filter(r => r.name !== '@everyone').forEach(c => {
            let list = roles.push(`${c.name} ${spaces.substring(c.name.length)} ${c.members.size} member`);
            if(c.members.size < 2) roles.push(`${c.name} ${spaces.substring(c.name.length)} ${c.members.size} member`);
            if(c.members.size >= 2) roles.push(`${c.name} ${spaces.substring(c.name.length)} ${c.members.size} members`);
        });
        msg.channel.send(`\`\`\` ${roles.join('\n')} \`\`\``);
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to split the list of roles into multiple messages to post them. You could e.g. send 50 per message, or you could count the number of characters you've got and split them at the point the next role would take you over 2000 characters.

Comment: I know but i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's probably because you are pushing to the array 2 times for each role

Once here:

`let list = roles.push(${c.name} ${spaces.substring(c.name.length)} ${c.members.size} member);`

And another time after that with the if statements,

After you change it to one time, it should fix it unless you have like 100 roles, and in which case you can just add the option `split: true` inside of `message.channel.send`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/SplitOptions

````js
if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}roles`)) {
    const spaces = '                      ';
    const roles = [];
    msg.guild.roles.filter(r => r.name !== '@everyone').forEach(role => {
        let string = `${c.name} ${spaces.substring(c.name.length)} ${c.members.size} member`;

        if (role.members.size >= 2) {
            string += "s";
        }

        roles.push(string);
    });
    //all those escape characters look bad, just concat strings
    msg.channel.send("```\n" + roles.join('\n') + "\n```", { split: true });
}
````

Comment: can i ask you one more question please.How can i make the list by the order of the roles , meanwhile the roles list shows like the order in server settings

Comment: What do you mean "by the order of the roles"? Alphabetically?

Comment: Not  alphabetically, just how the order is in the server settings roles because in this command the roles show up randomly

Comment: Looks like it is ordered from server settings, it's just from bottom to top, use `.reverse()` and it should work the way you want.